# Python 2.7 class attribute strange behavior

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary

Take this as a an example:

```
class Lizard(object):
    dict_class_var = {"first": "jon", "last": "do"}
    string_class_var = "monkey"


def test():
    liz1 = Lizard()
    liz1.dict_class_var['first'] = "david"
    liz1.string_class_var = "lion"
    print "dict: {}".format(liz1.dict_class_var)
    print "str: {}".format(liz1.string_class_var)

    liz2 = Lizard()
    print "dict: {}".format(liz2.dict_class_var)
    print "str: {}".format(liz2.string_class_var)

    liz3 = Lizard()
    print "dict: {}".format(liz3.dict_class_var)
    print "str: {}".format(liz3.string_class_var)
```

The `Lizard` class has two class-level attributes. In `test`, I'm initializing 3 variables with `Lizard()` and I'm expecting that all of them point to same `dict_class_var` and `string_class_var` which I have updated with `liz1` but this is the output:

```
dict: {'last': 'do', 'first': 'david'}
str: lion
dict: {'last': 'do', 'first': 'david'}
str: monkey
dict: {'last': 'do', 'first': 'david'}
str: monkey
```

Why the dict has been updated for all of them but the string has not?

Comment: Because a dictionary is *mutable*. `liz1.string_class_var = "lion"` assigns a new string object to a instance attribute.

Comment: @Martijn: That's not really a duplicate.  That is asking why class variables are shared.  The OP seems to know that, and wants it; this is about why the data is *not* shared.

Comment: @BrenBarn: yes it is; it tells you that assigning to the instance means you are not sharing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Maybe, but that's not the focus of the question.  It seems clear to me that the issue here is that the OP doesn't realize that `instance.obj = blah` sets an instance attribute even if the class attribute already exists.  (There's probably a dupe of that too, but I can't find one at the moment.)

Comment: @BrenBarn: several answers there address instance vs. class attributes, in the context of a mutable class attribute. This is just another variation of a FAQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did different things to them.  For the dict, you did this:

```
liz1.dict_class_var['first'] = "david"
```

This modifies the existing dict.

For the string, you did this:

```
liz1.string_class_var = "lion"
```

This does not modify the string, but sets the attribute to a *new* string.  Since you set the attribute on the instance `liz1`, it sets it on the instance, not the class.

If you want to set the class attribute, you need to do `Lizard.string_class_var = "lion"`.

Note that even if the class already has an attribute of the same name, setting it on the instance creates a new instance attribute that shadows the class attribute.  If you want to assign to the class attribute you need to name the class explicitly.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer along with Martijn's comment made it clear to me.